# Restarting sound service?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

My macbook pro running Snow Leopard stopped making sounds a couple hours ago. I've found other reports of people with sounds working through headphones, but that's not the problem I'm seeing. I get no sound when my headphones are plugged in either.

I'm wondering if there's a LaunchAgent or LaunchDaemon to restart which would remedy this. I've already tried killing the coreaudio daemon (and it dutifully automatically restarted) but that didn't fix it.

I need to reboot for an OS update, so I think that'll probably rectify things.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 334, accepted):

`sudo pkill coreaudiod`

On older OSes:

You can kill the CoreAudio process by opening Terminal and running:

```
sudo kill -9 `ps ax|grep 'coreaudio[a-z]' | awk '{print $1}'`
```

It will restart automatically after a couple seconds.

That fixes some problems my aging MBP has been having, where it sometimes fails to detect headphones or decides the speakers aren't connected. No guarantees it will work for every audio problem, but it's worth a shot.

Source: [zakgreant on macosxhints forums](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showpost.php?p=564649&postcount=16).

Comment: `sudo pkill coreaudiod`

Comment: DO NOT use `kill -9` unless the process is not responding.

Comment: This worked for me with zsh: sudo kill -9 $( ps aux | grep 'coreaudio[a-z]' | awk '{print $2}' )

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't always help for Bluetooth advices – Apple please fix it

Comment: On macOS Ventura, trying to kill that process with `kill -9` will crash the OS and cause a complete system shutdown. Try the `sudo pkill coreaudiod` approach @berto suggested.

Answer (score 99):

`sudo pkill -9 coreaudiod` kills the coreaudio process immediately. MacOS will automatically restart the coreaudio daemon, which will fix audio output in most cases.

This works on all MacOS versions.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No need for `awk` shenanigans.

Answer (score 35):

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext 

sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
```

These two commands will unload then reload the audio kernel extension. This is cleaner than sending a kill signal but might need an adjustment for newer OS.

Comment: `Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil unload -p /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Kernel request failed: (iokit/common) unsupported function (-536870201)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Kernel request failed: (iokit/common) unsupported function (-536870201)}` is the result on macOS 12 Monterey.

Comment: Better answer. Fixed the issues that the accepted answer caused. Worked for me on Ventura 13.1.

Answer (score 14):

I am on 10.9.2 and have the same problem. Since there are two answers, I wanted to document my findings:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext 
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
```

These two commands will unload then reload the audio kernel extension. [This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/121342/5472) fixes my problem 100% of the time, So please upvote that original post

[This solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/64024/5472) did not work for me:

```
sudo kill -9 `ps ax|grep 'coreaudio[a-z]' | awk '{print $1}'`
```

It shuts down the internal speakers and sends the sound to my 27" monitor but does not bring back the sound to my internal speakers or headset. Perhaps in some cases it works, but hopefully this post might explain when to use one solution vs the other.

Comment: Apple High Definition Audio kext? Neat, I would not have figured that acronym without this context.

Comment: IMHO, the 'kill -9 `ps ax|grep 'coreaudio...' should always work without the need for a reboot. The restarted coreaudio daemon may pick an audio device which it finds first (no idea how the audio device is selected in that case), but you can reset to the wanted audio device by 'System Preferences...' -> 'Sound' settings. Also, for a browser session, you might need to select the appropriate audio device as well.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, a reboot is required to fix this. It's a poor fix since it seems to recover from the failure and not address the root cause. I would like to have, but have not yet discovered if there is another quicker/simpler method to get sound back...

Answer (score 2):

The polite way to do this is:

```sh
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.audio.coreaudiod
```

Please learn to avoid `kill -9` except where it's the only thing that works; it kills things so suddenly that their shutdown/cleanup handlers are not allowed to run, which can often leave things in a weird partial states that aren't handled by the software.

Comment: This one is tricky to learn as it requires to learn more than the "coreaudiod" name, but I like that. Elegance over brutality!

Answer (score 0):

Use `killall` command with `_coreaudiod` user as parameter:

```sh
echo -e "# CoreaudioD restart\nalias audiorestart=\"sudo killall -u _coreaudiod -SIGKILL\"\n" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
audiorestart
```